Wick-rotating Euclidean correlator into time-ordered Minkowski correlator
I'm computing the Fourier transform of the 2point correlator in CFT of a scalar field with scaling dimension $\Delta$.
I have a result for the Euclidean case, found by
$$\int d^d x e^{-ik\cdot x} \langle \phi(x) \phi(0)\rangle = \frac{\pi^{d/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}-\Delta\right)}{\Gamma(\Delta)} \left(\frac{k^2_E}{4 }\right)^{\Delta- d/2}.$$
From this result it should apparently be straightforward to compute the time-ordered correlator in Minkowski by simply performing a Wick rotation and adding the Feynman $\epsilon$ prescription.
To me this doesn't seem so obvious. Specifically my questions are

Why does Wick rotating Euclidean to Minkowski suddenly imply time-ordering?
What $\epsilon$ prescription should I use ($\pm i \epsilon$)? How do I know this is the correct one?


You should check https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00014

Apart from the paper suggest by Connor, I strongly recommend David Simons-Duffin's lecture notes on Lorentzian CFT: https://www.desy.de/~bargheer/string-journal-club/presentations/2023-05-16_Sebastian-Harris_Simmons-Duffin:_TASI-Lorentzian-CFT.pdf. I will write one answer in the next couple days when I get some free time, but the basic point is that whatever you get in Lorentzian signature depends on the $i\epsilon$ prescription you chose (or equivalently the path of analytic continuation). Depending on the choice you can either get Wightman, time-ordered or anti-time-ordered correlators.

Wick rotating doesn't give you automatically a time-ordered correlator and the reason is exactly the point (2) of your question: there are many different ways in which you can continue the correlator, and each of them will give you a different thing in Lorentzian signature.
There are two ways to go about this: the first is to use the $i\epsilon$ prescription. The second is to use analytic continuation through paths as in the reference suggested by Connor in comments. I will here use the simplest approach of the $i\epsilon$ prescription and comment on the use of paths in a bit. I am also going to restrict to CFT on Minkowski space, are there are also some caveats when carrying out this analytic continuation on the cylinder.
First, the general prescription is this: let there be given some Euclidean correlator $\langle O_1(\tau_1,\vec{x}_1)\cdots O_n(\tau_n,\vec{x}_n)\rangle_E$ where $\tau_i$ are the Euclidean time coordinates and the subscript $E$ means this is an Euclidean correlator. Then we set $\tau_i = i(t_i-i\epsilon_i)$ with $\epsilon_1>\cdots> \epsilon_n$ to get the operator ordering $O_1\cdots O_n$. When we do this we get the Wightman function
$$\langle\Omega|O_1(t_1,\vec{x}_1)\cdots O_n(t_2,\vec{x}_n)|\Omega\rangle = \langle O_1(\tau_1,\vec{x}_1)\cdots O_n(\tau_n,\vec{x}_n)\rangle_E|_{\tau_i=i(t_i-i\epsilon_i)}.$$
Let us consider the two-point function
$$\langle O(\tau_1,\vec{x}_1)O(\tau_2,\vec{x}_2)\rangle_E = \dfrac{1}{|\tau_{12}^2+\vec{x}_{12}^2|^{\Delta}}$$
where I denote $\tau_{12}=\tau_1-\tau_2$ and $\vec{x}_{12}=\vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2$. We observe that upon analytic continuation the result will depend on $\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2 = \pm \epsilon$, where I defined this $\epsilon$ to just factor the sign which is what really matters when picking the orderings. The prescription gives the two possible Wigthman functions $$\langle \Omega|O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)|\Omega\rangle = \dfrac{1}{(-(t_{12}-i\epsilon)^2+\vec{x}_{12}^2)^\Delta},\quad \langle \Omega|O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)|\Omega\rangle = \dfrac{1}{(-(t_{12}+i\epsilon)^2+\vec{x}_{12}^2)^\Delta}.$$
We can also put together the time-ordered correlator, because the Wightman functions are its bulding blocks:
$$\langle T\{O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)\}\rangle = \langle \Omega|O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)|\Omega\rangle \theta(t_1-t_2)+\langle \Omega|O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)|\Omega\rangle\theta(t_2-t_1).$$
Now expand $(t_{12}\pm i\epsilon)^2 = t_{12}^2 \pm 2i t_{12}\epsilon -\epsilon^2$. We discard $\epsilon^2$ and realize that since $\epsilon\simeq 0$ is infinitesimal, we can replace $2i t_{12}\epsilon$ by $i\operatorname{sgn}(t_{12})\epsilon$. If we follow this procedure the time-ordered correlator is
$$\langle T\{O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)\}\rangle = \dfrac{1}{(-t_{12}^2+\vec{x}_{12}^2+i\operatorname{sgn}(t_{12})\epsilon)^\Delta}\theta(t_1-t_2)+\dfrac{1}{(-t_{12}^2+\vec{x}_{12}^2-i\operatorname{sgn}(t_{12})\epsilon)^\Delta}\theta(t_2-t_1).$$
Note now the support of the theta functions ensures that you always just have $+i\epsilon$. You can then factor the two-point structure and sum up the theta functions to one to get the time-ordered two-point function
$$\langle T\{O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)\}\rangle = \dfrac{1}{(-t_{12}^2+\vec{x}_{12}^2+i\epsilon)^\Delta}.$$
By the exact same argument the anti time-ordered two-point function is
$$\langle AT\{O(t_1,\vec{x}_1)O(t_2,\vec{x}_2)\}\rangle = \dfrac{1}{(-t_{12}^2+\vec{x}_{12}^2-i\epsilon)^\Delta}.$$
So:
(1) Wick rotating doesn't suddenly imply time-ordering. If you start with a Schwinger function, i.e., Euclidean correlator, there is a choice of analytic continuation path to Lorentzian signature, which is roughly equivalent to a choice of $i\epsilon$ prescription. This choice will give you different possible operator orderings.
(2) The $i\epsilon$ is dictated by the rule outlined above. Choosing $\epsilon_1>\cdots>\epsilon_n$ will pick one particular Wightman function with that given ordering.
Some subtleties in this whole procedure:
(1) There is a sense in which the analytic continuation along paths, instead of $i\epsilon$, is a tiny bit more general from the math perspective, because it allows for paths with non-trivial winding numbers around the insertion points. It is not fully clear, however, at least for me, if these have any reasonable physical interpretation. But that is just to point out that the two procedures are not entirely equivalent, only on a subset of the cases.
(2) The analytic continuation along paths is usually more appropriate to study higher-point functions such as the four-point function. See the paper linked by Connor for a complete example.
(3) The procedure of trading $-(t_{12}- i\epsilon)^2$ on the two-point structure by $-t_{12}^2+i\operatorname{sgn}(t_{12})\epsilon$ is almost ways done without much comment in Physics but is rather subtle from the point of view of distribution theory. Recall that the $\epsilon\to 0$ limit should always be understood in the distributional sense. For more on this see the discussion around equation 5.14 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.02090


Recall that spatially separated operators commute
$$\begin{align} [A(x),B(y)]~=~&0\quad{\rm if}\quad{\rm Re}\{(x\!-\!y)^2\}~>0~, \cr x^2~:=~&x^{\mu}g_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu}.\end{align} \tag{1}$$
Statement (1) is true in both Euclidean (E) & Minkowski (M) (possibly complex) spacetime (with mostly plus signature). For a real Euclidean spacetime, this means that operators at different spacetime points commute.

Recall that the time-evolution operator (in case the Hamiltonian $H$ has no explicit time dependence) is
$$ U(t_E)~=~e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H t_E} 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
U(t_M)~=~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}H t_M}.\tag{2}$$
This leads to a Wick-rotation
$$ t_E~=~e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon)}t_M ~=~i(1-i\epsilon)t_M~=~it_M+\epsilon{\rm sgn}(t_M),\tag{3}$$
where the infinitesimal $\epsilon>0$ is introduced to avoid crossing any branch cuts, i.e. we Wick rotate an angle slightly less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

In the Heisenberg picture
$$ A(t_E)~=~U(t_E)^{-1}A(0)U(t_E)
\quad\text{and}\quad
A(t_M)~=~U(t_M)^{-1}A(0)U(t_M).\tag{4}$$
A 2-point correlation function takes the form
$$\begin{align} \langle\Omega | A_2(t_2^E)A_1(t_1^E)|\Omega\rangle~=~&\langle \Omega | A_2(0)U(t_2^E\!-\!t_1^E)A_1(0)|\Omega\rangle, \cr 
\langle\Omega | A_2(t_2^M)A_1(t_1^M)|\Omega\rangle~=~&\langle \Omega | A_2(0)U(t_2^M\!-\!t_1^M)A_1(0)|\Omega\rangle. 
\end{align}\tag{5}$$

Assuming that the self-adjoint Hamiltonian $H$ is bounded from below but unbounded from above, we need the Euclidean 2-point correlation function to be time-ordered
$$ {\rm Re}(t_2^E\!-\!t_1^E)~>~0 ,\tag{6}$$
in order for the evolution operator $U(t_2^E\!-\!t_1^E)$ in the 2-point correlation function (5) to be bounded/exponentially decaying/mathematically well-defined.
In contrast the Minkowski 2-point correlation function is mathematically well-defined for any real $t_1^M,t_2^M\in\mathbb{R}$ in any order, since the evolution operator $U(t_2^M\!-\!t_1^M)$ is then unitary.
In particular, Minkowski correlation functions with time-ordering $T$, anti-time-ordering $AT$, or with fixed ordering (=Wightman), make mathematical sense.

The Osterwalder-Schrader reconstruction theorem reconstruct a Wightman 2-point correlation function
$$ \langle\Omega |A^M_2(t_2^M)A^M_1(t_1^M)|\Omega\rangle~=~\langle\Omega |A^E_2(\epsilon_2\!+\! it_2^M)A^E_1(\epsilon_1\!+\!it_1^M)|\Omega\rangle \tag{7}$$
from an Euclidean 2-point correlation function,
where $0<\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2$ are an infinitesimal version of ineq. (6).

The Wick-rotation (3) of ineq. (6) leads to
$$ t_2^M\!-\!t_1^M~>~0 ,\tag{8}$$
i.e. the time-ordered Euclidean 2-point correlator function is Wick-rotated to the time-ordered Minkowski 2-point correlator function
$$  \langle\Omega |T\{ A_2(t_2^M)A_1(t_1^M)\}|\Omega\rangle. \tag{9}$$

This generalizes to $n$-point correlation functions. For further details about e.g. branch cuts, monodromy, distribution theory & test functions, etc., see e.g. Refs. 1-3.


References:

T. Hartman, S. Jain & S. Kundu, Causality Constraints in CFT, JHEP 05 (2016) 099, arXiv:1509.00014; Chapter 3 (hat tip:Connor Behan).

D. Simmons-Duffin, 2019 TASI Lectures on CFT in Lorentzian Signature; Chapter 2.

P. Kravchuk, CFTs in Lorentzian signature, part 1, LonTI lectures, Spring 2024, YouTube video; 1:15:30-1:34:00.


